# Is_unique form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a CMS backend,and I use Codeigniter to help with the development.

So, I am working on a user table. For example, I allow the backend admin to insert, update the user info.

First there is a table of the user, for each row there is an "edit" button. After clicking on the "edit" button, there is a form for that particular user.

e.g.

```
UserName: Mr. ABC
Email: abc@a.com
Password: 1234
```

Since I need to ensure the username is unique and email is unique, I need to use isUnique validation

However, the problem is, how to handle the case, **"only the user modify the data, then add the is Unique rule"**? Because if I don't change the username, then I will pass the original name to check , and it can not pass the is Unique check , thanks

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|is_unique[admin.username]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the userID anyway to the server in order to update, You can run a query to check if that username/userID combo exists. if it does, that mean this user didn't change. if it doesn't, you need to check further with is_unique.

That's probably best implemented in a callback if you insist of using form_validation.

basically in your controller you'll two functions

```
function form_grabber()
{
//get your form and stuff. run this line : 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Username', 'call_back_isUserNameNotChanged[userID]'); 
//assuming userID comes from the form aswell.
}

function isUserNameNotChanged($username,$userID)
{
//query DB, return true if match exists or false if it doesn't
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I wonder is it the standard apporach, since checking on the update data is very common operation, I doubt why it makes it so complicated

Comment: It's really not that complicated, It just seems so if you're not used to form_validation.
all form_validation does is run a few functions to check if the conditions are met and returned true, you can always run this condition outside of the form validation. I honestly never liked the built in class :)

Comment: Should I just display the old data on top of the input box instead of inside the input box, so I will not post those empty field and only check the edited field

Comment: You can always store the username in a hidden field, and then check on the server if the hidden field matchs the name in the input field.

**HOWEVER** this is not a secure way, those values could have been tampered with. You'll WANT server side validation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `codeigniter` much, so I'm not sure the exact code to go about this, but how about something like this:

```
$current_name = // current name in db

if ($this->input->post('name') != $current_name) {
    // Name has been changed. Do validation.
}

...
```

Basically, just check if the posted name is different than what is already in the db. If so, run your validation and do your update. If it's the same, just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks. It is more complex than what I expected, all I need is to update data, but ensure that it is unique, so is it better I leave an empty input box to the user?

Comment: so that I can only set rules to those non empty field

Comment: No, I don't mean leave an empty input field... I assume you are filling in that field with the current name... on submit just check if the submitted field is different than the current value of name. If it is different, run your validation. If it's not different, the user didn't change his name, so you don't have to bother validating it or updating it.